# How can I reshape a table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I need to reshape a single column table with the next format:

| Year | foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1999 | 10 | 30 | 20 |

to the format:
|  Category   | value |
|-----|-------|
| foo | 10    |
| bar | 30    |
| baz | 20    |

I kinda know how to use pandas pivot and pandas melt, but for some reason, it's not working with my table.
I made the table extracting a single row from a bigger one containing more years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calling `pd.melt` on your data works for me, with pandas version 1.4.3

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Year": [1999],
    "foo": [10],
    "bar": [30],
    "baz": [20],
})
pd.melt(df)
```

Outputs:

```
  variable  value
0     Year   1999
1      foo     10
2      bar     30
3      baz     20
```

Comment: OMG, It actually worked. I don't know what I was doing wrong, but it was as simple as that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) :

```
out = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']).rename(columns={'variable':'Category'})

print(out)

  Category  value
0      foo     10
1      bar     30
2      baz     20
```